# Is it faster to get warmer in warm vapor or in warm liquid?

Tags: temperature, density

Is it faster to get warmer in warm water vapor or in warm water in liquid form?

Comment: Liquid transfers heat faster than gas.

Comment: After taking a sauna in the winter, have you ever stepped outside into the cold air? If the outside temperature is below zero deg, you do not feel as cold as if you jump into a pool, which ha $T\approx 10°C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they are at the same temperature, you will get warmer faster in the liquid. The heat transfer between the liquid/gas and your body in this case is caused by fast moving liquid/gas molecules colliding with your body and transferring some kinetic energy to the molecules in your skin. In a liquid there would be more collisions per second between the gas and your body and so heat would transfer faster.

Comment: What about the latent heat of vaporization? Doesn't that increase the heat transfer power of water vapor over liquid water"

Comment: If there's condensation of the vapour (on the body) then that increases heat transfer but hot liquid generally still trumps hot vapour.

Comment: There are a lot of possible variables. Is there convection? What compounds are we working with? What actual temperature are the body and gas/liquid at? etc. Unless someone can give a good argument otherwise I believe the liquid usually wins out, yeah.